# When can I access the mines?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

I really need some silver (then surely some gold) to upgrade my tools, but it's the third of summer and the mine isn't open. I'm aware of there *being* a mine due to in-game references to it, but I don't know where it would be (aside from one of the assorted blocked off passages) or when I will be able to access it.

When and how do I get to the mines to get silver and other minerals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlocking the mine is a bit of an involved process.  There are several steps that you need to follow.

From [Fogu's Forest Mine page](http://fogu.com/hm11/activities/mining.php):

> 1. Have Tina's House, Clement's Restaurant, and Rod's Cottage build. Tina's is from Town Renovation Plan #2 and Clement's and Rod's are from Town Plan #3.
> 2. Find the hidden music sheets in their houses. Find Tina's first, Clement's second, and then finally Rod's hidden sheet.
> 3. Buy the Doctor's House blueprints from Rebecca for 2400 G and construct the house using your farm workshop. The necessary materials are 3 Iron, 15 Small Lumber, 40 Lumber, and 65 Material Stone. You can buy Iron from Rebecca for 510 G each.
> 4. Once you place the house and Klaus moves in, Aaron will tell you about the music sheet hidden in Klaus' house.
> 5. Find the Boulder Dance sheet music on the first floor of the doctor's house and return back to Aaron to play it on the musical tree stumps: So-Mi-Do-Mi-Fa-Mi-So

So basically, you need to finish the second town renovation, and buy the blueprints for a couple houses after that.  Technically, all you need is the sheet music from the Doctor's house, but the order it gives it to you is pre-determined.  You won't find the one you need until you find all the others that come before it.  You don't need to play it, but it'll probably be useful for you to do so; it unlocks shortcuts for you to get around (and one expands the town area, I believe).

Once you play the Boulder Dance sheet music, that opens up the mine for you.

Note: The mine works differently in A New Beginning than in other Harvest Moons; there are three mining spots inside, and each gives you a random number of times you can mine it every day.  You no longer dig through floors to find the stuff you need.